# 1c Битрикс или сортировка найденного товара

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

у меня есть стандартный компонент bitrix:component.search , настройки его никак не менялись, стандартные, не кастомизирован никак, проблема заключается в том, что я ну никак не могу заставить его сортировать найденный товар по цене, чтобы сразу после поиска он автоматически выводил товар с сортировкой по цене, от большей к меньшей... гуглил-наткнулся на кусок кода вот здесь, но увы...нуль эмоций от сортировки

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic43895/

но применить его никак не получается...подставлял переменную согласно своим данным, а именно вместо 'catalog_PRICE_' подставил 'CATALOG_PRICE_1', ибо именно в ней у меня хранятся цены...
компонент, повторюсь, стандартный, а сортировать теми же стандартными средствами не хочет, хоть из кожи вон лезь...

`CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$El    = new CIBlockElement;
$dbRes = $El->GetList(
    array(
        'SORT' => 'ASC',
    ), array(
    'NAME'                  => '%' . $_GET['q'] . '%',
    'IBLOCK_ID'             => 1,
    'ACTIVE'                => 'Y',
    '>CATALOG_PRICE_1'      => 1,
    'SECTION_GLOBAL_ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    'SECTION_SCOPE'         => 'IBLOCK',
    array(
        'LOGIC' => 'OR',
        array('!PREVIEW_PICTURE' => false),
        array('!DETAIL_PICTURE' => false),
    ),
), false, false, array('ID')
);`

```
if (count($arIds) < 10 && changeLang($_GET['q']) != $_GET['q']) {
$dbRes = $El->GetList(
    array(
        'SORT' => 'ASC',
    ), array(
    'NAME'                  => '%' . changeLang($_GET['q']) . '%',
    'IBLOCK_ID'             => 1,
    'ACTIVE'                => 'Y',
    'SECTION_GLOBAL_ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    'SECTION_SCOPE'         => 'IBLOCK',
    '>CATALOG_PRICE_1'      => 0,
    array(
        'LOGIC' => 'OR',
        array('!PREVIEW_PICTURE' => false),
        array('!DETAIL_PICTURE' => false),
    ),
), false, false, array('ID')
);
while ($arRes = $dbRes->Fetch()) {
    $arIds[] = $arRes['ID'];
}
```

}

```
    $arElements = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:search.page",
    "empty",
    Array(
        "RESTART"                                      => $arParams["RESTART"],
        "NO_WORD_LOGIC"                                => $arParams["NO_WORD_LOGIC"],
        "USE_LANGUAGE_GUESS"                           => $arParams["USE_LANGUAGE_GUESS"],
        "CHECK_DATES"                                  => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
        "arrFILTER"                                    => array("iblock_" . $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"]),
        "arrFILTER_iblock_" . $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"] => array($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"]),
        "USE_TITLE_RANK"                               => "N",
        "DEFAULT_SORT"                                 => "sort",
        "FILTER_NAME"                                  => "NoFilter",
        "SHOW_WHERE"                                   => "N",
        "arrWHERE"                                     => array(),
        "SHOW_WHEN"                                    => "N",
        "PAGE_RESULT_COUNT"                            => "( 20 - count($arIds) )",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"                            => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"                         => "N",
        "PAGER_TITLE"                                  => "",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"                            => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE"                               => "N",
        "CACHE_TYPE"                                   => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME"                                   => 3600 * 100,
    ),
    $component,
    array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
);
```

вот, собственно, сам компонент... что делать-ума не приложу...

Comment: А куда именно вы пихали "CATALOG_PRICE_1"?

Comment: тут правильнее задать вопрос: а какие у вас товары? с торговыми предложениями или без?

Answer (score 1):

Этот компонент не для поиска товара, а для поиска любого контента. Там нет понятия цены и "из коробки" только два вида сортировки согласно [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/settings/search/components_2/search_page.php).  Иную сортировку надо реализовывать самостоятельно. Есть [статья](https://va-soft.ru/blog/sort-forsearch-results-bitrix/) в которой есть пример доработки сортировки. В ней задача несколько другая, но как заготовку можно использовать. При этом надо учесть следующие моменты:
1. Не забудьте ограничить область поиска только товарами либо продумайте куда при такой сортировке должна попасть, например, найденный контент (не товар)
2. Код, из приведенной выше статьи, вам необходимо доработать запросом цены. (Обратите внимание, что в статье далее найденные ID передаются компоненту типа bitrix:catalog.section, но настроить сортировку по цене только в нем не достаточно, т.к. ИД передаются постранично).
3. Обязательно закешируйте потом результат.

Кстати, если вам реально не нужна морфология и гибкость поиска и достаточно поиска в имени по точному нахождения фразы - тогда можно вообще без компонента поиска. И без вашего запроса в начале. Передавайте сразу ваш фильтр в компонент bitrix:catalog.section.